# A-frame Raycaster not working (need intersection point with a-sky)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe, virtual-reality

Ok so am trying to find the coordinates of the intersection of the ray 
caster with the a-sky but the problem is a) i cant see the ray caster although i add showline:true 
b)intersection listener is never accessed (intersections are never 
triggered)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/aframe-animation-component@3.0.1"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/aframe-event-set-component@3.0.1"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/aframe-layout-component@3.0.1"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/aframe-template-component@3.1.1"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            AFRAME.registerComponent('collider-check', {
                dependencies: ['raycaster'],
                init: function () {
                this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected',
                                         function (evt) {
                    alert(evt.detail.intersection.point);
                    console.log('Player hit something!');
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene>
            <a-sky class="collidable"  src="{{asset('img/3_Entree_2.jpg')}}"> </a-sky>
            <a-camera look-control collider-check>     
                <a-entity raycaster="objects: .collidable" position="0-0.9 0"
                          rotation="90 0 0" showLine= "true"></a-entity>
            </a-camera>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting so the raycaster can reach the sky.

`raycaster="far: 10000"` or `<a-sky radius="100">`

Comment: thank  you but i think my problem was with the syntax of the ray caster it should have looked more like this : <a-entity raycaster="showLine: true; far: 100" line="color: orange; opacity: 0.5"></a-entity>

Answer (score 0):

my problem was with the syntax of the ray caster it should have looked more like this :

```
    <a-entity raycaster="showLine: true; far: 100" line="color: orange; 
    opacity:0.5"></a-entity>
```

A-frame documentation is yet weak and syntax usage is not clear